# Loading spinner wrongly taking too much space

Tags: html, css

I wish to use a 197px X 196px spinner on top of a fullscreen background-image but with the code I am using, it takes the whole space (enormous!).

I just would like it to be at the center of the page with its "normal size", that is to say 197px X 196px

Here is a Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boqzNb

HTML

```
<div id="toto" class="" style=" background: #DF2943 url('https://www.ramtrucks.com/shared/htmlcolorizer/images/colorizer/spinner_animation02.gif') center;background-size:cover;"></div>
```

CSS

```
#toto {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I know the issue comes from the property 'cover' but in the project
I need the property background-size absolutely. On the 'click' event on a certain button, I inject via javascript into the URL a real image and I use background-property 'cover' so that it creates a fullscreen background image. Can I keep cover and 100% width & height for the final real image but restrict the size of the loader while it appears (loader disappears when the final image has fully loaded) ?

It should eb possible to have a 100% width and height background image and until it finishes to load a loading gif with a full REd color in the background and a loading gif on top of it but that this loading gif does not take the whole screen (quite ugly).

How can I manage this?

Comment: Remove `background-size` property and add `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: I can't. For my project this is absolutely needed as I use fullscreen pages that stretch to all the size. I need 'cover'. i aill try to add no-repeat though

Comment: I am injecting dynamically an image to replace the url and it becomes a rela image that needs to be fullscreen with property 'cover'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width and height are percentages of the container of the element. If you specify `width: 100%`, you're asking for the element to take up 100% of the container, so yes, it's going to be the whole screen.

If you want the width to be 197 pixels, use `width: 197px`. The same goes for height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I edited my question, I need the property  background-size absolutely. On click on a certain button, i inject via javascript into the URL a real image and I use background-image cover so that it creates a fullscreen background image. Can I keep cover and 100% for the final real image but restrict the size of the loader while it appears (loader disappears when the final image has fully loaded) ?

Comment: @Mathieu But if the background size property has to be `cover` for the image your loading and you aren't changing it dynamically prior to that happening, then the background size will always be set to cover which will stretch your loading gif.

Comment: @Mathieu Then dynamically change the background-repeat/size/etc at the same time you change the background image. You can't apply `cover` and expect it to apply to one image and not the other, you need to change the background URL **and** any relevant styling yourself.

Comment: @defteH not sure to understand what you mean. the final image needs property 'cover' and width=100% and height=100%.While it loads, i want to show a full mono-color background (red for example) and at the center a spinner but this spinner should be at its real size not stretched to the 100% width

Comment: @meagar: ok i think so too. But how can I keep a 100% red color background and only apply the change of size (to sth small) to the loading gif ? will look into this

Comment: @Mathieu You can't apply styles to the gif, you apply styles to the element. Wherever your code is for dynamically applying a new background, you need to **at that time** also apply whatever other relevant style changes.

Comment: @Mathieu as meagar said, you're applying the `cover` to the element during loading AND its persisting when you inject the new image URL. You need to change the `cover` property dynamically as well..

Answer (score 0):

Use next code:

`<div id="toto" class="" style=" background: #DF2943 url('https://www.ramtrucks.com/shared/htmlcolorizer/images/colorizer/spinner_animation02.gif') center center no-repeat;"></div>`

it will centered you preloader and no repeat and there is no background-size property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I edited my question, I need the property  background-size absolutely. Can't do without

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the width and height of the spinner, give it these settings to have it in original size and center inside its container (which in the codepen is the window):

```
#toto {
  width: 196px;
  height: 196px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEZeLj

Answer (score 0):

The html

```
 <div id="toto" class=""></div>
```

The css you need to set background style and keep div size is

```
 #toto {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#DF2943;
    background-image: 
    url('path/spinner_animation02.gif');
    background-size: 195px 195px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

Hope it helps!